# jPanelMenu and scrolling not working together

Tags: javascript, scroll, conflict, jpanelmenu

> **UPDATE - The Solution**
>
> I finally found the solution... and it is super simple!
>
> just add the following to your css:
>
> `body { overflow-x: visible; }`
>
> It seems the conflict arises when overflow-x is set to hidden on the
>   body by jPanelMenu.

I am running jPanelMenu and jRespond together *(jPanelMenu is only active on smaller screens thanks to jRespond, on larger screens the menu is fixed and does not use jPanelMenu)*.

All is working fine but when I try to use any kind of js to apply css on page scroll, it doesn't work while the jPanelMenu is active.

I want to add a floating menu button to open the jPanelMenu once the user scrolls past the header, which only needs to be active when jPanelMenu is active.

Here is one of the scroll snippets I have been using:

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scroll >= 200) {
        $("#scroll-trigger").addClass("show");
    } else {
        $("#scroll-trigger").removeClass("show");
    }
});
```

This works on its own, as do a number of other different ways to write out this scroll method.
But when jPanelMenu is on, this scroll code is rendered useless somehow.

Here is another that I found on codrops, it also works on it's own but conflicts with jPanelMenu:

```
var cbpAnimatedHeader = (function() {

    var docElem = document.documentElement,
        header = document.querySelector( 'header' ),
        didScroll = false,
        changeHeaderOn = 300;

    function init() {
        window.addEventListener( 'scroll', function( event ) {
            if( !didScroll ) {
                didScroll = true;
                setTimeout( scrollPage, 250 );
            }
        }, false );
    }

    function scrollPage() {
        var sy = scrollY();
        if ( sy >= changeHeaderOn ) {
            classie.add( header, 'bodhi-header-shrink' );
        }
        else {
            classie.remove( header, 'bodhi-header-shrink' );
        }
        didScroll = false;
    }

    function scrollY() {
        return window.pageYOffset || docElem.scrollTop;
    }

    init();

})();
```

I couldn't find anything in the code personally and have searched online for similar and tried sooooo many different ways of implementing it's not funny. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the solution... and it is super simple!

just add the following to your css:

`body { overflow-x: visible; }`

It seems the conflict arises when overflow-x is set to hidden on the body by jPanelMenu.

Comment: Hey Benbodhi,
I ran into a problem configuring the two as well. Do you mind if I ask you a question? Or is it better to just start a new thread?

Answer (score 0):

jpanelmenu is a scary plugin, use sidr (http://www.berriart.com/sidr/)

Comment: I have indeed used sidr thank you. Had trouble with similar scrolling problem on mobile with sidr aswell.